# NSOperation & NSOperationQueue Cancellation

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I'm encountering some weird issues with some custom `NSOperation` instances queued in an `NSOperationQueue` instance:

When I call either `[myOperation cancel]` or `[myOperationQueue cancelAllOperations]` the `isCancelled` getter for the `cancel` boolean remains unchanged for my custom `NSOperation` subclass instances.

I'm trying to cancel the operations when the app delegate `applicationWillResignActive` method is called.

My implementation for `NSOperation` subclass is like this:

- custom init method
- implemented main

I have a singleton with strong references to the instances of my `NSOperation` subclass and `NSOperationQueue` instance.

In a method of that singleton I do the following:

```
myNSOperationQueueInstance = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
myCustomOperation_1 = [MyCustomOperationClass alloc] customInit];
myCustomOperation_2 = [MyCustomOperationClass alloc] customInit];

[myNSOperationQueueInstance addOperations:@[myCustomOperation_1,myCustomOperation_2] waitUntilFinished:NO];
```

Until now, everything works as expected, the custom operations start executing.

However, when I call another method of my singleton from `applicationWillResignActive` to cancel my custom operations using either `[myCustomOperation cancel]` or `[myNSOperationQueueInstance cancelAllOperations]` the `isCancelled` boolean remains unchanged (I check for `isCancelled` periodically in the execution loop of my custom operations).

Another interesting thing is that in the same method which should cancel the operations, if I check with NSLog the `isCancelled, isExecuting, isAsynchronous` the booleans are set to `NO` but the `isFinished` boolean is set to `YES`even though the operations are executing at that time.

Also, if I try to see what operations are queued in my `NSOperationQueue` using the `operations` property, the array is empty.

If I override the `cancel` property and its setter method of `NSOperation` subclass, it works as expected.

I also requested a long running background task from the system which works just fine so the problem isn't that the app becomes inactive before the operations could cancel.

What am I missing? Why the `isCancelled` getter doesn't change, why the `operations` array property of `NSOperationQueue` is empty despite the fact I added the operations and they're executing while interrogating the array and why the `isFinished` boolean is set to `YES` while the operations are executing?

Comment: just checking , did you call `[myCustomOperation start]` on your custom NSOperation?

Comment: No because they're not concurrent and I don't want to start them manually. I want to allow the NSOperationQueue to start them. I also did not override the `start` method of the subclass.

Comment: And your `-main` is synchronous? It doesn't return until the operation is completely finished?

Comment: so your operation usually doesn't return until completely finished? Can you clarify? Your code says `[myNSOperationQueueInstance addOperations:@[myCustomOperation_1,myCustomOperation_2] waitUntilFinished:NO];`

Comment: Can you post code of your `[MyCustomOperationClass customInit]`?

Comment: @lead_the_zeppelin I was playing with `waitUntilFinished` to see if it matters and I copied the last change here :). It seems it doesn't matter because the `isFinished` boolean is `YES` whatsoever.

Comment: @KenThomases You were right about your assumption: since I use the operations to import to Core Data, the method called from `-main` was inside the `performBlock` of the `ManagedObjectContext` I was using to import so whatever code was running inside the operation was running on another thread :). Thanks to you and `lead_the_zeppelin` I was able to pinpoint the flaw (lead_the_zeppelin made me look again at my init method and since it was just above `-main` I could see what's in there :D. Thank you guys! I managed to get the expected results after modifying my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to *@KenThomases* and *@lead_the_zeppelin* (see the comments in the OP) I was able to pinpoint the flaw in my code:

Since I created the custom `NSOperation` subclass to import data to a Core Data model, my flaw was that the code which performs the import called from the `-main` method of the subclass, was embedded inside the scope of the block callback of the asynchronous `performBlock` method of the `ManagedObjectContext` that I am using to manage the import execution.

So what happened was that the code inside `-main` was running asynchronously in another thread than my operation instance which, not surprisingly, was reporting that it finished its execution. In my case, to fix the issue, I changed `performBlock:` with `performBlockAndWait:`.

**Conclusion**: if you ever encounter the same issues like me, check if the code running inside your custom `NSOperation` subclass `-main` instance method doesn't run asynchronously.